# Parametric plot of a cone in Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, plot

i have a cone, which is described as in the figure:

[image]

(two bases are ellipses)

How can i plot the surface by Mathematica?

Comment: Did you try something? Post it!

Comment: You should post _at least_ the equations for the upper and lower ellipses in Cartesians. Just to alleviate the trig calc for the answerers.

Comment: The illustration appears to be (approximately) an illustration of the *frustrum* of a cone.

Comment: You can choose arbitrary parameter for two bases.

Comment: I try a Mathematica code for a normal frustrum:

h = 0.5; a = 1; b = 0.6;
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[t] (a (h - u) + u b)/h, 
  Sin[t] (a (h - u) + u b)/h, u}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, h}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]

but it need the surface as in the figure.

Comment: In your figure `Cos[alpha] = H/L` So, alpha, H and L can not be simultaneously parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a RegionPlot:

```
RegionPlot3D[ Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 1 - z/3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -1, 1}, 
              BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you modify the position as in the figure?

Comment: Have you set the angle of the frustrum and ellipses bases?